# Execute AsyncTask with POST

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I already have executed async task procedure, but this time I should execute an asynk task sending two params, that need to complete my query in php file. They are an ID and a Date, that i store in two textview and I get with getText().toString(). Below is my EDITED Class and the Async Task, however params doesn't arrive to php query. Over all, i have tried also to test php file and related query, and it seems work properly.
I don't know how to send this data. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
public class Activity3 extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView IdentitaColl,DataSearch;
Intent intent;
GridView appGrid;

String myJSON;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
private static final String TAG_DATA = "Data";
private static final String TAG_START ="OraInizio";
private static final String TAG_END ="OraFine";
private static final String urlAgenda = "http://www.xsite.com/testparams.php";


JSONArray dati_cal = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_app;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_esitoagenda);
    intent = getIntent();
    IdentitaColl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_identcoll);
    DataSearch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_datasel);
    appGrid= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvApp );
    list_app = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    riportaParametri();

    String clID = IdentitaColl.getText().toString();
    String aData = DataSearch.getText().toString();
    Log.i("DATA Scelta: ","" +aData);
    Log.i("ID Collab ", "" + clID);

      getData();
     }

private void riportaParametri() {
    String pkg = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    String tCode =  intent.getStringExtra(pkg + "IDCOLL") + "\n";
    String tData =  intent.getStringExtra(pkg + "DATA") + "\n";
    IdentitaColl.setText(tCode);
    DataSearch.setText(tData);

}

protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        dati_cal = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<dati_cal.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = dati_cal.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String dataap = c.getString(TAG_DATA);
            String oStart = c.getString(TAG_START);
            String oEnd = c.getString(TAG_END);
            HashMap<String,String> impegni = new HashMap<String,String>();
            impegni.put(TAG_ID,id);
            impegni.put(TAG_DATA,dataap);
            impegni.put(TAG_START,oStart);
            impegni.put(TAG_END,oEnd);
            list_app.add(impegni);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Activity3.this, list_app, R.layout.activity_esitoagenda,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_DATA,},
                new int[]{R.id.tv_id,R.id.tv_datasel}
        );
        appGrid.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlAgenda);
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;

            try {
                String clID = IdentitaColl.getText().toString();
                String aData = DataSearch.getText().toString();

                List<NameValuePair> valuePairs = new ArrayList<>(2);
                valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clID", clID));
                valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("aData",aData));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valuePairs));
                Log.i("entity", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"+valuePairs);

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                inputStream = entity.getContent();


                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity3.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Obtaining list...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_seleziona_data, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: If you're not having issues with PHP, there is no need to tag it.

Comment: I didn't know...sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the values to asynctask. do it this way.

```
.execute(param1, param2);
```

If your question is different please be more clear.

Comment: yes, this is just what i mean. I didn't know where put params to send. So, if i have understood,  i have two TextView, i could get value of two tv like so: String xxx = mytv1.getText().toString() and String yyy = mytv2.getText().toString() and then .execute(xxx,yyy) Concerning php? How i have to identify this string? $data=POST['xxx'] ?

Comment: you can pass the data as json.

Comment: StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
entity.setEntity(se);

Comment: As you can see, i have edited this code, and if i log nparams i can see the data to send. This data doesn't arrive to php file, infact if i read echo from query, parameter 'aLav' is empty. I don't be able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**JSONParser.java** - Create a file JSONParser.java and put the code into the file. You have to use this file to send request to server and to parse the response.

```
public class JSONParser {

/* Defining all variables */

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

/* Get Json object as respective response to url */
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, JSONObject jObj) {

Log.v("Requ. URL: ",url);
// Making HTTP request
try {
    // Default Http Client
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Http Post Header
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jObj.toString());
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    // Execute Http Post Request
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
/*
 * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
 * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the BufferedReader
 * return null which means there's no more data to read. Each line will
 * appended to a StringBuilder and returned as String.
 */
try {
    // Getting Server Response
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    // Reading Server Response
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}

// try parse the string to a JSON object
try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}

   // return JSON String
    Log.e("JSON Parser", jObj.toString());
    return jObj;
}

}
```

**Write below code to your Activity/Fragment:**

```
// Async Class for fetching live metal price from webapi
private class YourClassToFetchData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

// getting parameters sent by execute() method.
String id = params[0];
String date = params[1];

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(
            URL, getConvertedinJson(id,date));

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

**Method to create keys/parameters in `JSON` form**

Write this method to same Activity/Fragment where you have created the `AsyncTask` class

```
private JSONObject getConvertedinJson(String idString, string dateString) {

JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
try {

   // put your parameter's name correctly at the place of ID and Date
    object.put("ID", idString); 
    object.put("Date", dateString);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
   Log.v("JObj", "JObj " + object.toString());
   return object;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I will try separately you posted code and i will give you the response. However this, doesn't change my question...Where is the error in my code? Apparently it seems ok, i can read passed parameter from log... I ask to myself if error could be in php file, but i have tested it without post variable and it works properly...

Comment: Please, can you tell me how call your class 'YourClassFetchData'?  if i call it Youretc(); gives me red flag.

Comment: you have to call `new YourClassFetchData().execute(id,date);`

Comment: Thank you, however i obtain this error:  Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value SELECT of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject, But it seems that values are correct: E/JSON Parser﹕ {"aData":"2015-9-28","clID":"2"} What else it's possible to do?